# dailymotion API PHP question

Tags: php, api, vimeo

The following code works for Vimeo API:

```
function getTitle($id){
    $title = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$id.php"));
    $theTitle=$title[0]['title'];
    echo $theTitle;
}
```

If for Dailymotion I use:

```
 $id2 = 'xks75n';
    function dailyMotionTitle($id2){
        $dm = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/".$id2));
        echo $dm[0]['title'];
    }
```

I get Error at offset 0 of 1374 bytes. I know I can use embed.ly or JSON parsing but I prefer PHP. Any help concerning repair of Dailymotion PHP parsing is appreciated.

Comment: This url returns the given video

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just change URLs and expect this to work.

Read through the [Dailymotion APIs documentation](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/index.html) pages to learn how to access video information programatically.

As one example, using the REST API, to get the title of your video in a JSON formatted response, fetch:

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xks75n?fields=title
```

Which returns

```
{
    "title": "The Farmer and His Sons- Aesop's fables"
}
```

---

Another option is to use the [oEmbed API](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/oembed.html) on the URL you have in the question.

```
http://www.dailymotion.com/services/oembed?format=json&url=http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xks75n
```

Which returns

```
{
    "type": "video",
    "version": "1.0",
    "provider_name": "Dailymotion",
    "provider_url": "http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com",
    "title": "The Farmer and His Sons- Aesop's fables",
    "author_name": "hooplakidz",
    "author_url": "http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/hooplakidz",
    "width": 480,
    "height": 269,
    "html": "<iframe src=\"http:\/\/www.dailymotion.com\/embed\/video\/xks75n\" width=\"480\" height=\"269\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",
    "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/static2.dmcdn.net\/static\/video\/369\/709\/34907963:jpeg_preview_large.jpg?20110830044159",
    "thumbnail_width": 426.666669846,
    "thumbnail_height": 240
}
```

---

Hint: you can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to "decode" that into a PHP object or array to access the value(s).

Answer (score 2):

You might have better luck with

```
'https://api.dailymotion.com/video/'. $id2 .'?fields=title'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use php the easy way is to use Dailymotion PHP SDK :
https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-php

```
<?php
$api = new Dailymotion();
$result = $api->get('/video/' . $id, array('fields' => array('title', 'channel'...)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dailymotion have great [API Documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#graph-api).

Try

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/'. $id2 .'?fields=title
```